# Help needed with ampscript RegExMatch funcation parameters

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We try to extract attributes using RegExMatch function from the strings with format of

`"row=10#seat=15#barcode=9X4H341ZTKTPMintT#price=140.00"`

to store them as individual variables. Unfortunately, I'm not very experienced with regular expressions syntax. Would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Here are examples from adam Spriggs: https://sprignaturemoves.com/regex-in-ampscript/ . Furthermore you can test on https://regex101.com/

Comment: Adam, thank you! I went through it and it's very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a pro in RegEx but i would go for something like

```
%%[
    var @s,@p_row, @p_seat, @p_barcode, @p_price
    var @row, @seat, @barcode, @price

    set @s = '"row=10#seat=15#barcode=9X4H341ZTKTPMintT#price=140.00"'

    set @p_row = '^.*row=(.*)#s'
    set @p_seat = '^.*seat=(.*)#b'
    set @p_barcode = '^.*barcode=(.*)#p'
    set @p_price = '^.*price=(.*)"'

    set @row = RegExMatch(@s, @p_row, 1)
    set @seat= RegExMatch(@s, @p_seat, 1)
    set @barcode= RegExMatch(@s, @p_barcode, 1)
    set @price= RegExMatch(@s, @p_price, 1)

]%%

Row:%%=v(@row)=%%<br>
Seat: %%=v(@seat)=%%<br>
Barcode: %%=v(@barcode)=%%<br>
Price: %%=v(@price)=%%<br>
```

The first one isn't working properly but this one does:

```
%%[
    var @s, @p_row, @p_seat, @p_barcode, @p_price
    var @row, @seat, @barcode, @price

    set @s = '"row=10#seat=15#barcode=9X4H341ZTKTPMintT#price=140.00"'
    set @p_row = '^.*row=(.*)#s'
    set @row = RegExMatch(@s, @p_row, 1)

    set @s = '"row=10#seat=15#barcode=9X4H341ZTKTPMintT#price=140.00"'
    set @p_seat = '^.*seat=(.*)#b'
    set @seat= RegExMatch(@s, @p_seat, 1)

    set @s = '"row=10#seat=15#barcode=9X4H341ZTKTPMintT#price=140.00"'
    set @p_barcode = '^.*barcode=(.*)#p'
    set @barcode= RegExMatch(@s, @p_barcode, 1)

    set @s = '"row=10#seat=15#barcode=9X4H341ZTKTPMintT#price=140.00"'
    set @p_price = '^.*price=(.*)"'
    set @price= RegExMatch(@s, @p_price, 1)
]%%

Row:%%=v(@row)=%%<br>
Seat: %%=v(@seat)=%%<br>
Barcode: %%=v(@barcode)=%%<br>
Price: %%=v(@price)=%%<br>
```

And possibly the best solution:

```
%%[
    var @s
    var @p_allvar
    var @row, @seat, @barcode, @price

    set @s = '"row=10#seat=15#barcode=9X4H341ZTKTPMintT#price=140.00"'
    set @p_allvar = '^.*row=(.*)#seat=(.*)#barcode=(.*)#price=(.*)"'
    set @row = RegExMatch(@s, @p_allvar, 1)
    set @seat = RegExMatch(@s, @p_allvar, 2)
    set @barcode = RegExMatch(@s, @p_allvar, 3)
    set @price = RegExMatch(@s, @p_allvar, 4)


]%%

Row:%%=v(@row)=%%<br>
Seat: %%=v(@seat)=%%<br>
Barcode: %%=v(@barcode)=%%<br>
Price: %%=v(@price)=%%<br>
```

Comment: Awesome job,  Johannes! Thank you so much! If anyone encounters alike problem there is also a good resource to test your regular expressions - https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

A solution using SSJS (don't think it's the best though because using `eval`):

```
%%[
   VAR @attributes
   SET @attributes = "row=10#seat=15#barcode=9X4H341ZTKTPMintT#price=140.00"
]%%

<script runat=server>
     Platform.Load("Core","1");

    //Variable from AMPscript
    var attributes = Variable.GetValue("@attributes");

    var arr = attributes.split('#');
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
       var variableName = arr[i].split('=')[0];
       var variableValue = arr[i].split('=')[1];
       eval(variableName + " = " + "'" + variableValue + "'");
    }

//To get the variables back in AMPscript
  Variable.SetValue("@row",row);
  Variable.SetValue("@seat",seat);
  Variable.SetValue("@barcode",barcode);
  Variable.SetValue("@price",price);

</script>

<br>
<b>row:</b> %%=v(@row)=%%
<b>seat:</b> %%=v(@seat)=%%
<b>barcode:</b> %%=v(@barcode)=%%
<b>price:</b> %%=v(@price)=%%
```